# How can I sync to extension local storage in content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Now I use `chrome.extension.sendMessage` in content script and `chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener` in background script. But the problem appears when I need to sync to extension's local storage in real time (several checkboxes with options in extension popup).

Popup with checkbox (to control content-script.js options) -> checkbox state stored in extension's local storage.

Content script need to know changes made by user in popup window -> send request to Background page to access extension's local storage keys.

Background page -> send response to Content script -> callback function replicate all keys from extension's local storage to web local storage.

Content script read replicated keys and turn on/off it's options.

But this process is not real-time and I need it to be reactive.

Content-script.js:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    name: "cache"
},
function(response) {
    var status = response.url;
    if (status == 'enabled') {
        localStorage['cache'] = 'enabled';
    }
    if (status == 'disabled') {
        localStorage['cache'] = 'disabled';
    }
}
);
```

Backround.js:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("request recieved is " + request);
    if (request.name == "cache") {
        sendResponse({
            url: JSON.parse(localStorage['cache']).status
        });
    } else {}
}
);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: From your content-script I see that `localStorage['cache']` is a string, but in your background.js you seem to be doing a `JSON.parse()` on it. Is that the error you are referring to?

Comment: No, it's not error. I'm parsing extension local storage record that has a value like {"status":"enabled"}.
The problem is in real-time syncing between extension and web local storage. I need the same record as in extension local storage when user opened extension's popup, clicked checkbox and it's state changed, then script made record in extension local storage.

Comment: So you use the key "cache" for the extension's localStorage as well as for the website's localStorage, but on the extension it's a JSON string whereas on the website it's a simple string?

Comment: Just saying, `chrome.extension.sendMessage` and friends are deprecated in favour of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`

Comment: Doesn't matter, I can fully replicate keys with JSON values or not. It is only sample, the main idea is to sync keys in real time.

Comment: So ... if you want to trigger the update of the website's localStorage directly on change of the checkboxes in the extension's popup, why don't you use chrome.tabs.sendMessage from the background script and chrome.runtime.onMessage on the content script? This way you would be able to trigger the change immediately

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked into the `chrome.storage` API? One of the specific use cases it's designed for (an advantage over `localStorage`) is that content scripts can access this API directly, removing the need for messaging to communicate with your background page. (You might even be able to eliminate the background page altogether.)

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: Thanks for such a nice hint! That was pretty easy and worked like a charm.